# In Aniara, in year six, what is blocking Mimarobe’s door that horrifies and breaks her?

Tags: aniara

It’s when she heads home after completing her beam-screen to replace the long-gone Mima.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aniara_(film))

> ... she learns that Isagel has committed suicide and has also killed the child they were raising together, after learning that the algae tanks the passengers rely upon for food and water have become contaminated.

In this instance, she appears to have strangled herself to death using a doorhandle.

[image]

It's not immediately obvious how she killed her child, but presumably she drowned him in the bath, since Mimarobe finds his body in the en-suite bathroom.